# ListView with custom ArrayAdapter - thread issue

Tags: java, android

I'm trying to create a ListView with custom ArrayAdapter.
Following the example from here.
In the code below, I've created a ListActivity.
This list is getting its value from custom ArrayAdapter - OrderAdapter.
OrderAdapter is getting its elements from ArrayAdapter

I'm using runOnUiThread to fill the elements in adpater.
But inside this thread's run() method, the code is going into infinite loop. (See comments below).
Please check why it not getting out of the for loop.

Code:

```
public class SoftwarePassionView extends ListActivity {

    private ProgressDialog m_progressDialog = null;
    private ArrayList<Order> m_orders = null;
    private OrderAdapter m_adapter; // Defined Below
    private Runnable viewOrders;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.softwarepassionview);
        m_orders = new ArrayList<Order>();


        viewOrders = new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                getOrders();
            }
        };

        Thread thread = new Thread(null, viewOrders, "MagnatoBackground");
        thread.start();
        m_progressDialog = ProgressDialog.show(SoftwarePassionView.this, "Please Wait",
                "Retriving data", true);

        this.m_adapter = new OrderAdapter(this, R.layout.row, m_orders);
        setListAdapter(this.m_adapter);
    }

    private void getOrders() {
        try {
            m_orders = new ArrayList<Order>();
            Order o1 = new Order();
            o1.setOrderName("T-Shirt Purchase");
            o1.setOrderStatus("Dispatched");
            Order o2 = new Order();
            o2.setOrderName("Deo Purchase");
            o2.setOrderStatus("Pending");
            m_orders.add(o1);
            m_orders.add(o2);

            Thread.sleep(2000);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Toast.makeText(this, e.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
        runOnUiThread(returnRes);
    }

    private Runnable returnRes = new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            if (m_orders != null && m_orders.size() > 0) {
                m_adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                /*
                 * Going in an infinite loop below
                 */
                for (int i = 0; i < m_orders.size(); i++)
                    m_adapter.add(m_orders.get(i));
            }
            m_progressDialog.dismiss();
            m_adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    };

    private class OrderAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Order> {

        private ArrayList<Order> items;

        public OrderAdapter(Context context, int textViewResourceId,
                ArrayList<Order> items) {
            super(context, textViewResourceId, items);
            this.items = items;
        }

        @Override
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            super.getView(position, convertView, parent);
            View v = convertView;
            try {
                if (v == null) {
                    LayoutInflater vi = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
                    v = vi.inflate(R.layout.row, null);
                }

                Order o = items.get(position);
                if (o != null) {
                    TextView orderName = (TextView) v
                            .findViewById(R.id.topText);
                    TextView orderStatus = (TextView) v
                            .findViewById(R.id.bottomText);
                    orderName.setText(o.getOrderName());
                    orderStatus.setText(o.getOrderStatus());
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                Toast.makeText(SoftwarePassionView.this, e.toString(),
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
            return v;
        }
    }
}
```

Order.java

```
public class Order {
    private String orderName;
    private String orderStatus;

    public String getOrderName() {
        return orderName;
    }

    public void setOrderName(String orderName) {
        this.orderName = orderName;
    }

    public String getOrderStatus() {
        return orderStatus;
    }

    public void setOrderStatus(String orderStatus) {
        this.orderStatus = orderStatus;
    }
}
```

Comment: you should use [AsyncTask](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this...

make a methode in `OrderAdapter`

```
    setList(ArrayList<Order> items);
    {
        this.items.clear();
        this.items.addAll(items);
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
```

and in `run()` of UI Thread do

```
if (m_orders != null && m_orders.size() > 0) {
            m_adapter.setList(m_orders)  
            }
            m_progressDialog.dismiss();
```

EDIT do some refracting of your code...make  like this

- in onCreat() new SampleTask().execute();
  and

  public class SampleTask extends AsyncTask{

  ```
  @Override
  protected void onPreExecute() {
      super.onPreExecute();
      //show progress bar here

  }

  @Override
  protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
      //Do heavy work here
      return null;
  }
  @Override
  protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {

      super.onPostExecute(result);

      //Dissmiss the dialgo
      //call m_adapter.setList(m_orders)
  }
  ```

Comment: Thank you very much..it is now getting out of the loop and m_adapters is getting populated. But now it is not populating list on screen @ setListAdapter(this.m_adapter);

Comment: `items` are not null and have values? and where you are calling `setListAdapter(this.m_adapter);`

Comment: Sorry, `this.items.addAll(items);` is not adding values. But even if I use for loop instead and populate it, still not showing anything at `setListAdapter(this.m_adapter);` [last line of onCreate method]

Comment: Followed your advice...i believe i'm on right track, but facing an issue..opened a new question as it is not aligned with this one now:[here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11373193/android-asynctask-ui-update-issue)